# SQL join to override particular column of left table

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, join, rdbms

I have two tables namely, **Table1** and **Table2**
**Table1**

```
custId--custName--custAge
c1--c1name--32  
c2--c2name--41  
c3--c3name--41
```

**Table2**

```
custId--verified--custName  
c1--Y--c1FullName  
c2--N--c2FullName
```

I need to join Table1 and Table2, So that if verified column is Y in table 2, I need custName from Table2 instead of Table1.
So, desired output is: (**overwrite custName column from Table2 if verified column is Y for that custId**)

```
custId--custName--custAge  
c1--c1FullName--32  
c2--c2name--41  
c3--c3name--41
```

I wrote following query, which is not giving proper result. Please help.

```
select T1.custId, NVL(T2.custName, T1.custName),T1.custAge   
from Table1 T1  
left join Table2 T2 on T1.custId=T2.custId and T2.verified='Y'
```

Comment: [`NVL`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) is available in Oracle, so the RDBMS is Oracle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement to achieve this :

```
SELECT      tab1.custId,
            CASE
                WHEN (tab2.verified = 'Y')
                THEN tab2.custName
                ELSE tab1.custName
            END AS CustName,
            tab1.custAge

FROM        Table1 tab1
LEFT JOIN   Table2 tab2 ON tab1.custId = tab2.custId
```

See this here -> http://rextester.com/EVOMK25746 (*This fiddle is built on* `SQL Server` *, however, the query should work on* `Oracle` *databases as well*)

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this query once..

```
select * into #tab1 from
(
select 'c1' custId,'c1name' custName,31 custAge
union all
select 'c2' ,'c2name' ,41 
union all
select 'c3' ,'c3name' ,41 

) as a

select * into #tab2 from
(
select 'c1' custId,'Y'verified,'c1FullName' custName
UNION ALL
SELECT 'c2','N','c2FullName '
) as a

SELECT T1.custId,CASE WHEN T2.verified='Y' THEN T2.custName ELSE T1.custName END AS CUSTNAME,T1.custAge FROM #tab1 T1
LEFT JOIN #tab2 T2 ON T1.custId=T2.custId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select custId, custName, custAge
  from Table1
       natural join
       ( select custId 
           from Table2
          where verified='N' ) t2
union
select custId, custName, custAge
  from ( select custId, custAge from Table1 ) t1
       natural join
       ( select custId, custName
           from Table2
          where verified='Y' ) t2;
```